# sorting algorithm doesn't produce correct output

Tags: python

```
def sort(nums):
    finish = False
    while finish == False:
        finish = True
        for i in range(len(nums)-1):
            if nums[i] > nums[i+1]:
                t = nums[i]
                nums[i] = nums[i+1]
                nums[i+1] = t           
                finish = False

                print(nums)     
    return nums
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZPgu.jpg)

9 is clearly not greater than 101, so i dont know why it keeps getting swapped

Comment: You are sorting strings, not integers. As a string `'9'` is greater than `'101'`.

Comment: Variables should be compared to boolean literals using `is`, not `==`. While we’re on the subject, `finish == False` is just `not finish`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the sorting problem comes from the fact that your input is a list of `string`s and not `int`s. You can easily transform the values with a `list comprehesion`.

Two more comments: 1) Unlike other programming languages, in `python` you don't need to use a temporary variable to switch the values of two variables, and you can do it in 1 line instead of 3. 2) It's more accepted to use `while True` structure without pre-defining a special variable (e.g "finish") before the loop, and to use a `break` clause to get out of the loop.

So here is the fixed and modified code:

```
def sort(nums):
    nums = [int(n) for n in nums] #This is the neccesary line to fix the bug you are having
    while True:
        finish = True
        for i in range(len(nums)-1):
            if nums[i] > nums[i+1]:
                nums[i], nums[i+1] = nums[i+1], nums[i]
                finish = False
                print(nums)
        if finish:
            break
    return nums
l = ['1', '101', '9', '808', '54']
sort(l)
```

Output:

```
[1, 9, 101, 808, 54]
[1, 9, 101, 54, 808]
[1, 9, 54, 101, 808]    

Out[17]:

[1, 9, 54, 101, 808]
```